# How to take input from EditText, convert it into integer and display it on TextView in Android?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I've been trying to add numbers and display on screen using button on click listener... 
The code snippet is as follows :

```
add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stubi
String value = input.getText().toString();
int FValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
iCounter+=FValue;
display.setText("Total : "+iCounter);
}
});
```

When I try to run this code, my app crashes.. . Why??? 
Any help appreciated

Reading a couple of responses and experimenting, I changed my code to

```
 add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//String value = input.getText().toString();
int FValue = Integer.parseInt("15");
iCounter+=FValue;
display.setText("Total : "+iCounter);
}
});
```

And now it's perfectly adding 15 every time I click the button,so I guess the culprit is this code :
    String value = input.getText().toString();

Okay...
The Code I ran:

```
     add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
            String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
            if(!value.equals(""))
            {FValue = Integer.parseInt(value);}
            iCounter+=FValue;
            display.setText("Total : " + iCounter);
            }catch(Exception e)
            { e.printStackTrace();}
        }
});
```

The Error I got:
04-28 15:26:27.820: W/System.err(1319):     java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 15:26:27.820: W/System.err(1319):     at com.honeycomb.helloworld.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
04-28 15:26:27.820: W/System.err(1319):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
04-28 15:26:27.840: W/System.err(1319):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
04-28 15:26:27.840: W/System.err(1319):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-28 15:26:27.840: W/System.err(1319):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-28 15:26:27.840: W/System.err(1319):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-28 15:26:27.840: W/System.err(1319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-28 15:26:27.840: W/System.err(1319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 15:26:27.880: W/System.err(1319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-28 15:26:27.880: W/System.err(1319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
04-28 15:26:27.880: W/System.err(1319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-28 15:26:27.880: W/System.err(1319):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 15:26:41.790: W/System.err(1319):     java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 15:26:41.790: W/System.err(1319):     at com.honeycomb.helloworld.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
04-28 15:26:41.790: W/System.err(1319):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
04-28 15:26:41.800: W/System.err(1319):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
04-28 15:26:41.800: W/System.err(1319):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-28 15:26:41.800: W/System.err(1319):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-28 15:26:41.800: W/System.err(1319):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-28 15:26:41.810: W/System.err(1319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-28 15:26:41.840: W/System.err(1319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 15:26:41.840: W/System.err(1319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-28 15:26:41.840: W/System.err(1319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
04-28 15:26:41.850: W/System.err(1319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-28 15:26:41.850: W/System.err(1319):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Yikes!!! 
I accidently forgot to put

```
input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput);
```

Which led to all these errors. 
Anyways... First day with android. 
Could have been worse. 
Thankyou everyone for your help.

Comment: You should add log output.

Comment: How and when does it crash? Immediately when the app starts, or only when you click the button? What is the logcat error message? Just copy and paste it from the console to here. The one thing I'd check is that value is actually parsable to int type.

Comment: When I click the button add

Comment: Ok, execute the code in debug mode, put a break point at int FValue, and run the code. Check what is contained in value after you click Add. If you are having trouble using the logger, interpreting the messages, or using the debugger, then you maybe need some basic training in Eclipse first.

Comment: I've uploaded the log output

Comment: Guess I really need some help with the debugger... Will come back once I know how to workaround with the debugger. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use android:inputType="number" or something which will allow only numeric values.

you can do like this the parsing

```
try { 
        int FValue = 0;
        String value = input.getText().toString().trim(); // note trim()
        if(!entry.equals("")) 
          FValue= Integer.parseInt(value);

        iCounter+=FValue; // make icounter global instead of declaring in the onclick
        display.setText("Total : " + iCounter);
   } 
catch(Exception e) 
{ e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Hope it helps...

thx

Comment: Nope... due to try catch block, it isn't crashing when I press the button but it doesn't do anything else either

Comment: The stacktrace printed to screen should tell you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: Look for the messages in red as these are the error output. Get the latest one down the bottom. You should be able to double-click the error and it will take you to the line of code that is giving you a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
display.setText("Total : "+iCounter);
```

to:

```
display.setText("Total : "+ String.valueOf(iCounter));
```

Also try checking if iCounter was initialized, like `int iCounter = 0;`

Comment: There is no need to convert an int to a String when appending it to another String. The conversion is done automatically when using concatenation.